# git put two branches together

Tags: git, merge

It seems I overestimated my knowledge of git.

A week ago I started working on a project. I downloaded it from server and started doing usual workflow with git.

A few days later a client notified me that he decided to introcuded some "improvements" into his code. He is not programmer but anyway he wants to add some changes. So it's not option to learn him how to use git.

At first I thought that I would just download his code from server (I didn't upload any code to his server), create a new branch from it and merge it with my code.

So, what I did:
 I created a new branch being in master( where my code is) -

```
 git branch client_branch
 git checkout client_branch
```

Then I deleted all my code from the project's folder 
   and inserted only client's code.

I made a new commit in client_branch  -

```
git commit -m clients_changes
```

Then for safety I did:

```
git checkout master
git branch merging
git checkout merging
```

and in the end:

```
  git merge client_branch
```

It went fine. I got no conflicts. But I bet that there must be conflicts. Because now  I got not working version of code and all my changes  disappeared in some files completely.

Please help, is it possible somehow to save his and mine changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you checkout the `client_branch` before commiting `clients_changes` ? just executing `git branch client_branch` does not   set current branch to `client_branch`.

Comment: yes, I checkouted before commiting. I updated my question.

Comment: Did you do a diff to see what were the changes that the client made? If the merge didn't produce conflicts, **Then You Have No Conflicts.** However, just because you don't have any conflicts, it doesn't mean the code isn't broken (if that indeed is your case). How do you know that the client's code works? How do you know that it works **together with your code?**

Comment: "Then I deleted all my code from the project's folder and inserted only client's code...I got not working version of code and all my changes disappeared in some files completely." Well, if you deleted all of your files and replaced them with the client's version, why is it a surprise that some of your changes have been removed? Why did you remove your files completely? Normally, you would just copy files over and look at the diff of the changes before committing.

Comment: Ok, I wanted too much, code can be in not working state(it's ok). I'm more concerned that I lose my changes when I merge and it seems I get version of client put over mine. Following your advice I checked for differences doing command "git diff my_branch clients_branch" - http://minus.com/l8uxyiUBcYDTu . It looks like there are plenty of them. But when I run  "git merge client_branch" , git just merges and says that all is fine. More precisely - http://minus.com/lk1MQ1LTmtbvt . Maybe it's wrong stratage or something else what I can't get a clue

Comment: If I delete all code and copy clients code into a fresh folder - it happens faster rather than with moving over. It's just a trick.  Maybe it soudns silly, but I deleted everything from directory except .git folder. Before putting clients code, I create a new branch and then I make a new commit after copying clients code. Afterwards I can switch beween mine and not mine code using branches.  ( Yes, yes, perhaps it's a stupid way , but unfortunately I didn't think up nothing better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem is solved.

After playing for a long time with git diff  and looking how different versions of our code were I realised that  it would be too tedious to do it via console.

The core of the problem  can be represented so:

File A (mine):
  `The
 first 
 line`

File B(client's):

```
The 
second
line
```

If I do simple "git merge" command, independent in which branch I'm staying, I will get as result either first or second version of file.
But I need to be warned about every difference! Because I cannot say for sure which version is better.

The situation got even worse, because I used code formatter, which formatted code to make it look better (actually a good thing but  in this case it played a bad joke).

So I came  to usage of kdiff3 utility:

[image]

It allowed me manually to see differences between every file and to decide whether  I want to merge or not.

I must admit that it shouldn't be advised to get into such situations. But it happened so and I  didn't find any better solution.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problem is to find the revision that your client used to make his changes.
Let's say he used revision X

```
git branch client_changes X
git checkout client_changes
# Apply client changes
git branch merging master
git checkout merging
git cherry-pick client_changes # Apply the changes by the client
# Verify the changes
```

This way you can just apply the changes from your client to your version. But it is crucial that you find the base revision your client used, or at least as close as you can or else you undo your own changes when you overwrite your code with your clients code.

Comment: client didn't use git at all

Comment: But do you know which version you gave him as the base of his changes?